# Tortoise git bonobo server Permission denied upon push

Tags: git, tortoisegit, bonobo

I have on my pc a repository called Project.

when I try to pull everything works fine.
However if I try to push I have a fatal error:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': Unable to create 'C:/inetpub /wwwroot/bonobo/App_Data/Repositories/Project/refs/heads/master.lock': Permission denied
To C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bonobo\App_Data\Repositories\Project
! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bonobo\App_Data\Repositories\Project'

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (234 ms @ 22/06/2016 10:25:40)
```

It would look like I do not have the permissions to write files on repository.
However it is on my machine.

What's wrong ?

Comment: What's the path of your local repo? What's the remote setting of that repo?